# Problems with JTable and GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to set up a Panel that will hold two different tables, one that is 1/3 the width of the window, and another that is 2/3 the width of the window. Here is the demo code I've been testing with:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TableTest {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Frame");
    frame.setTitle("Logged In");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1000, 800);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints setup = new GridBagConstraints();

    JTable table1 = new JTable();
    table1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    setup.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    setup.weightx = 0.5;
    setup.weighty = 1;
    setup.gridx = 0;
    setup.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,5);
    tablePanel.add(new JScrollPane(table1), setup);

    JTable table2 = new JTable();
    table2.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    setup.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    setup.weightx = 1;
    setup.weighty = 1;
    setup.gridx = 1;
    setup.insets = new Insets(10,5,10,10);
    tablePanel.add(new JScrollPane(table2), setup);

    frame.add(tablePanel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

If I use JTextArea instead of JTable I get the right layout, two areas with one being 1/3 the width of the window and another being 2/3 the width. When I use JTable, I get two areas that are each 1/2 the width of the window.

Some of the things I've tried:

1. Setting gridwidth to 1 and 2 respectively
2. Setting fill to VERTICAL
3. Changing weightx

After every change, I still get two equally sized tables inside the window.

Things I haven't tried:
1. New Layout - I've been working with Swing for about a week so it's possible there is a layout other than GridBagLayout that solves this issue but my relative inexperience makes it difficult to know.

It seems like JScrollPane is ignoring my setup when using a JTable but I am unsure if this is true and if so, why it is true. Any assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a Picture of what I want the layout to look like:
[Layout Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCtQc.png)

**UPDATE**
Upon further testing, it seems to be an issue with the width of the window. If you drag the width of the window down below ~950 you'll notice the layout "snap" to the correct proportions. Perhaps this might hint at the culprit. I'm not sure if GridBagLayout acts differently at different window widths but I assumed it scales the same way at all sizes, which is the main reason I was using it.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). (Include the code imports and ensure it will compile and run for others as is.) 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: `frame.add(tablePanel);
    frame.setVisible(true);`  There should always be a `frame.pack()` after adding the last component and before setting the frame visible.  Doubt it is the exact problem here, but ensure it is done in order to remove all doubt.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks, I updated the code with imports and added frame.pack(). I wasn't using pack because it was messing up my window size. Also, as you expected, pack() did not change the size of the two tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a GridBagLayout the components are displayed at their preferred size when the frame is packed.

The `weightx` parameter only applies when the frame is resized. If the width is increased, then the extra spaces is allocated based on the relative `weightx` values.

So if you always want the tables to be in the 1/3, 2/3 ratio then you need to set the size of the tables in that initial ratio. For example:

```
JTable table1 = new JTable()
{
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(100, 100);
    }
};

...

JTable table2 = new JTable()
{
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(200, 100);
    }
};
```

Another option is to use the [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/). It was designed to always display components at their relative sizes:

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(RelativeLayout.X_AXIS);
rl.setGap(10);
JPanel panel = new JPanel( rl );
panel.add(new JScrollPane(table1), new Float(1));
panel.add(new JScrollPane(table2), new Float(2));
```

Comment: Setting the initial ratio solved the problem. Thank you for the help. I will check out Relative Layout as it seems to be a better solution.